# Coordinating long-running actions with independent threads

Tags: kinematics, servomotor, stepper-motor, real-time

Basically, some things have real-world durations that need to be accommodated.  For example, moving a servo arm 180° will take a significant number of milliseconds.

What is the best practice for handling that?  Farm the action off to a separate thread (including an appropriate `nanosleep()` for however long the motion should take), continue other processing, and then rendezvous with the servo action thread when you need it to have completed?

Are there (simple!) online examples, say in C or Python, showing how this can/should be done?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* RoUS, but I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Comment: I'm not not new to SE, and I'm not a fan of the 'experiment first, and only ask questions after you have problems' gating, but if that's how this specific SE site works I'll not fight it.  IMHO it makes an SE site a community primarily of use to experienced people and much less so to beginners in the topic  Thank you for your polite response, however!  I will seek the answer to this question elsewhere.

Comment: This question is so wide open that there's a semi infinite ways to suggest a solution to your stated problem that makes it hard to have a right solution. And even a "right" solution might not work for your use case. This is pretty strongly into the "bad subjective" area as outlined in this article: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ And as we're in a harder science area we do bias more on the factual. Because there are right and wrong ways to do threading, but it depends on your unstated requirements. Threading and coordination is a whole domain of study.

Comment: Threading was just an exanple.  My basic question that I asked myself was, "Do robotics applications have to factor the real-time duration of initiated actions into their processing?"  My answer was, "Sometimes.  Probably." :-D  The question I was trying to ask was, "Where can I find out more about this topic, particularly as it relates to the Pi?"  Which is still too wide-open, and I don't see how to narrow it, alas.

Comment: In C pthreads is a good starting place and python has built in threading libraries. There's whole books on them. If your looking for introductions to those topics I'd suggest looking for a book with a style you like. Or potentially an online class or tutorial on that topic. The needs for this aren't really robotics specific. There may be other resources on other stack exchanges too.

Comment: I'm not completely unfamiliar with threading; my question was how applications that mix compute processing with real-world manipulation coördinate them.  Such as serialising access to a servo (&c.), but dealing with interrupts before the motion-end time has arrived. and how that's typically done.  Threading I've done, but only for parallel software processing.  Mixing things that have measurable wall-clock duration with things that don't-care, however, not so much.  I'm only encountering it now from thinking through a Pi-based 'robotics' app.  Thanks!